# If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ is conditionally convergent, prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^+ = \infty = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^-$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ is conditionally convergent, prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^+ = \infty = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^-$ where $x_k^+$ are the positive terms and $x_k^-$ are the absolute values of negative terms of $x_k$.

> Proof: Suppose $x_k$ is only conditionally summable, this means that
>   the sequence $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|x_k|$ is not convergent.
>   Note that $s_n$ is a monotone increasing sequence that is not
>   convergent, hence it must be unbounded. But $\sigma_n^+ =
>  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_k^+$ and $\sigma_n^- =
>  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_k^-$ are all subsequences of $s_n$, and they
>   are monotone increasing as well.
>
> Thus, they must me also unbounded and 
>    $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^+ = \infty = 
>  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^-$. $\blacksquare$

EDIT: Here's my another attempt at proving this:

> Proof: Note that $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_k|$ is divergent to $\infty$.
>   But $s_n' = \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k$ converges to some finite number
>    $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\sigma_n^+ =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_k^+$ and
>    $\sigma_n^- =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_k^-$. Then, $s_n = \sigma_n^+ +
>  \sigma_n^- $ and $s_n' = \sigma_n^+ - \sigma_n^-$. Then, $s_n+s_n' =
>  2\sigma_n^+$ must diverge to infinity as $n\to\infty$ because $s_n$
>   diverges to $\infty$ and $s_n'$ converge to $L$. Any finite number
>   added to infinity is also infinity. This implies that $2\sigma_n^+$
>   must diverge as well as  $\sigma_n^+$.
>
> Likewise, $s_n'-s_n = -2\sigma_n^-$ must diverge to $-\infty.$ And
>   this implies $-2\sigma_n^-$ diverge to $-\infty$ and $\sigma_n^-$
>   diverges to $\infty$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Are you taking the absolute value of the negative terms? Otherwise, $\sum x_k^- = - \infty$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that $x_k^-$ has to be absolute value of the negative terms of $x_k.$

Comment: $\sigma_n^+$ and $\sigma_n^-$ are *not* subsequences of $s_n$. But your consideration on those partial sums is indeed a good beginning. As a possible angle of attack, you may utilize the relation $$s_n = \sigma_n^+ + \sigma_n^- \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k = \sigma_n^+ - \sigma_n^-$$ to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @SangchulLee Colud you please explain why they are not?

Comment: $\sigma_n^{\pm}$ are obtained by summing certain portion of summands of $s_n$. In other words, they may be understood as partial sums for certain subsequences of $|x_k|$'s. This is not the same as picking certain terms in the sequence $(s_n)$. Let me see if I can devise a simple example that easily demonstrates this difference.

Comment: @SangchulLee I see now why they are not subsequences, I drew a plot for each sequence and realized they were not the subsequences of $s_n$. But *if they were subsequences*, would my conclusion be valid? That is, any subsequence of a monotone increasing sequence that is unbounded will also be unbounded?

Comment: That is true. Any subsequence of a real sequence that diverges to $+\infty$ also diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Shorter argument: since the sequence is not absolutely summable, one of the two has to diverge; if only one diverged then the whole thing wouldn't be convergent.

Comment: @Ian That was short but it seems complete. Can it be accepted as a formal proof as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $x_k^{+} = x_k$ if $x_k \geq 0$, and $x_k^{+}=0$ otherwise. Notice $x_k^{-} = -x_k$ if $x_k \leq 0$, and $x_k^{-}=0$ otherwise.

Put 
$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_k|, \quad \sigma_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k, \quad \sigma_n^{+} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{+}, \quad \sigma_n^{-} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{-}.
$$
Note $$\sigma_n^{+} = \frac{1}{2}s_n + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_n.$$ Since $s_n$ diverges and $\sigma_n$ converges, we must have that $\sigma_n^{+}$ diverges. Moreover, as $\sigma_n^{+}$ is increasing, $\sigma_n^{+} \rightarrow \infty$.

Likewise, $\sigma_n^{-} = \frac{1}{2}s_n - \frac{1}{2}\sigma_n$ leads to $\sigma_n^{-} \rightarrow \infty$.