# If $\sum x_k$ is converges conditionally, then $\sum x^+_k$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, conditional-convergence

I'm working on this problem

> If $\sum x_k$ is a conditionally convergent series in $\mathbb R$, then $\sum x^+_k$ diverges where $x^+_k = \max \{x_k,0\}$.

Could you please verify if my attempt is correct or not? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

From $\sum |x_k|$ diverges, we get for all $\varepsilon >0$ $$\exists N_0 \in \mathbb N, \forall N>N_0: \sum_{k = 0}^N |x_k| =\sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k \ge 0}^N x_k - \sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k < 0}^N x_k \ge \varepsilon \tag{1}$$

Assume the contrary that $\sum x^+_k$ converges. Then there exists $\varepsilon' >0$ $$\forall N \in \mathbb N: \left | \sum_{k = 0}^N x^+_k \right |= \sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k \ge 0}^N x_k < \varepsilon' \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, there exists $\varepsilon' >0$ $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N_0 \in \mathbb N, \forall N>N_0:\varepsilon + \sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k < 0}^N x_k < \varepsilon'$$

As such, $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ has a subsequence of negative terms that converges to $ -\infty$. Thus $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ diverges, which is a contradiction. In conclusion, $\sum x^+_k$ diverges.

Comment: Hi @RobertZ, I would like to fix my mistake by myself. Could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178090/if-sum-k-1-inftyx-k-is-conditionally-convergent-prove-that-sum-k-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If I look at your link @RobertZ, I will already know the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $x_k=x_k^{+}-x_k^{-}$. If $\sum x_k^{+}$ converges then so does $\sum x_k^{-}$ because it is given that $\sum x_k$ converges. It now follows that $\sum |x_k|=\sum x_k^{-} +\sum x_k^{+}$ converges and this is  a contradiction.

Comment: I would like to fix my mistake by myself. Could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: Your proof is fine up to the last part. To get a contradiction you have to observe that that $\sum x_k^{-}$ has to be convergent; this is what I started with in my answer.

Comment: Please check if my reasoning is correct! From $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N_0 \in \mathbb N, \forall N>N_0:\varepsilon + \sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k < 0}^N x_k < \varepsilon'$$ I get $$\sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k < 0} x_k$$ diverges and thus $$\sum x^-_k = \sum_{k = 0 \atop x_k < 0} (-x_k)$$ diverges. From $\sum x_k = \sum x^+_k -\sum x^-_k$, we get $\sum x_k$ diverges, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not recognize where I missed the minus sign in the previous comment. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Your proof is fine now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support :)))))